# Google Charts - Invalid syntax or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I am fetching data from mysql to be plotted in a pie chart.
I am doing this in python flask which uses jinja template syntax.
I would like to display a pie chart.

The debugger shows me this

[image]

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Shock', 'Number'],
               {% for record in data %}
                 ['{{record.shockStatus}}', {{record.number}}],
               {% endfor %}
```

I can see the values in the console. But it kept saying invalid syntax or token. Would appreciate if you can point out where have I done wrong. Thank you.

**Updates**

What are contained in the data.

```
[{u'number': 7, u'shockStatus': u'absent\r\n'}, {u'number': 7, u'shockStatus': u'present\r\n'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

- Your input data has embedded newlines. You probably want to fix that at the point where you produce the data, in Python code.
- You are interpolating raw data as if it is JavaScript safe. Don't do that. Use the [`tojson` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/latest/templates/#tojson) to produce Javascript compatible syntax.

From Python, convert your `data` sequence into a the correct format for Javascript, that is, in pairs of shockStatus and number values:

```
# if you have dictionaries
data_transformed = [[r['shockStatus'].strip(), r['number']] for r in data]
# or if you have objects with attributes
data_transformed = [[r.shockStatus.strip(), r.number] for r in data]
```

I've included a `str.strip()` call in there to remove the newline and other leading or trailing whites pace from your `shockStatus` values.

the pass that to your template and use:

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Shock', 'Number'],
                {{ data_transformed|tojson|safe }}
 )];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I hit an error which is 

TypeError: Undefined is not JSON . So I removed tojson. 

After I removed, I hit another error which is "Unexpected token for" in the data_transformed statement

Comment: Oh I solved it in another way. But I appreciate your help and advice. There are still a lot of things for me to learn. :) Your answer is useful in helping me to solve the problem.

Comment: @Sofia: The TypeError means that the `data_transformed` was not defined; you didn't pass it to the template in a `render_template()` call.

Comment: @Sofia: the Undefined value without `tojson` then leads to an empty string being inserted, so then Javascript is unhappy, because there is nothing there anymore.

Comment: I did pass it into the template:P

Comment: @Sofia: yet if you get the `Undefined` error, then there was an error in what you passed in somewhere. To the template, the name was not set.